# Returning zero results on multiple conditions codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am currently doing a airline reservation. The fields/radio button/dropdown I have are: 2 radio button(One way, Round trip), 2 dropdown(From ,To:), 1 text field.

After filling up these fields and tried to click the "Search now". It returns no result.

NOTE: My columns on the flight table are: flight_name, flight_destination, flight_depart. I also tried to print/var_dump my variable inside of my search_result both model and controller, the value is correct/right

I also tried to print $table(it getting my flight table), $testing - getting my value, $testing2 and $testing3 is also correct but when I tried to print $query it is NULL/ retuns 0 result.

**Model**

```
public function search($table, $flight_from, $flight_to, $depart)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $table = $this->db->from($table);
    $testing = $this->db->where('flight_name',$flight_from)
    $testing2 = $this->db->where('flight_destination',$flight_to)
    $testing3 = $this->db->where('flight_depart',$depart);

    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();



}
```

**Controller**

```
public function search()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">', '</div>');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('flight_from', 'Select depature', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('flight_to', 'Select Destination', 'required|trim');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('depart', 'Date', 'required|trim');


        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->index();

        } 
        else 
        {
        $search_result = array(
            $flight_from = $_POST['flight_from'],
            $flight_to = $_POST['flight_to'],
            $depart = $_POST['depart']
        );
        $data['search_result'] = $this->CrudModel->search('flight',$flight_from,$flight_to,$depart);

        $this->load->view('result',$data);
        }
    }
```

Question: How is it returning zero result? Even though there's an existing data. Is my query wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your POST variables values? Are they what you expected to be? Or you can dump the SQL statement executed behind and try to see if you get any results executing it from a SQL client.

Comment: Yes, I already check it for nth times.. The value Im getting is also correct

Comment: What about the SQL query statement if is executed manually, do you get any results? I mean to dump $this->db->get()->getSQL();

Comment: So it will become like this? $query = $this->db->get()->getSQL();? If yes, it gives me an error Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::getSQL()

Comment: Than try to dump the result of  $this->db->last_query();  before your return statement,

Comment: What is the expected output if I put it? Because it's also the same, no returning value

Comment: It will output the exact query that your search method will generate. This way you check if correct or not.

Comment: array(0) { } is the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145796/discussion-between-bds-and-angel).

Answer (score 0):

```
public function search($table, $flight_from, $flight_to, $depart)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->where('flight_name',$flight_from)
    $this->db->where('flight_destination',$flight_to)
    $this->db->where('flight_depart',$depart);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```